# Как обеспечить доступ к скриптам, чтобы к ним могли обращаться несколько программистов?

Tags: php, поиск-программ

**Ситуация:** Пытаюсь "сколотить" команду программистов. Работать будем в одном офисе, есть локальная сеть. Программировать преимущественно будем на PHP. При написании кода использую PHP Storm и тестирую с помощью OpenServer.

**Вопрос:** Как обеспечить доступ к скриптам? Делать дубликаты файлов, работать с ними, а потом по кускам вставлять код — по-моему, это глупо. Может быть как-то нужно настроить OpenServer для совместного доступа к директории с сайтом, чтобы мы могли одновременно работать?

Пока писал вопрос, уже понял, в какую сторону "копать", но все же может быть есть какие-то программы для совместной работы программистов.

Comment: вам поможет git

Comment: спасибо, попробую разобраться, может еще кто какие варианты предложит?

Comment: svn, но вы сами потом перейдете на гит и будете рвать волосы из-за потраченной пары лет

Comment: понял, буду разбираться с git, спасибо!

Comment: и заведите виртуалку с линуксом.

Comment: Еще посмотреть на Bitbucket.  
У него неограниченное число приватных репозиториев для команды до пяти человек.

Comment: Наткнулся на отличный [доклад Линуса](http://lib.custis.ru/%D0%9B%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%81_%D0%A2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B4%D1%81_%D0%BE_GIT_%D0%BD%D0%B0_Google_Talks) о git.

Сам не люблю эти VCS (хотя, конечно, пользуюсь SVN), но почитав Линуса думаю, надо попробовать git.

Comment: > может еще кто какие варианты предложит?

Ну mercurial еще можно. Он самую малость полегче гита в освоении.

Comment: Для облегчения совместной работы можно сделать связку redmine + git.

Comment: На вопрос можно дать объективный ответ: автор ищет способ получения доступа к скриптам с разных компьютеров.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Идите на [GitHub](https://github.com) он решит Вашу труднейшую задачу :)

Comment: Всем спасибо за ответы!

Answer (score 1):

1. [Jira](https://www.atlassian.com/software/jira) Для постановки задач и
       контроля их выполнения (10 баксов в год за 10 человек)
2. [HipChat](https://www.atlassian.com/software/hipchat)
       Для общения внутри команды. -
       бесплатно (бесплатно если не пользоваться видео и аудио звонками)
3. [BitBucket](https://www.atlassian.com/software/bitbucket/overview) - реп, 5 юзеров бесплатно, в отличии от гитхаба репы можно делать закрытыми. На гитхабе бесплатный доступ не дает возможности делать закрытые репы (ваш проект будут видеть все).

Все эти продукты одной замечательной конторы atlassian. Интегрируются между собой, и образуют достаточно комфортную экосистему. Удобно управлять задачами и контролировать их выполнение.